# Python 3 - Mac OS X newer version of tkinter displays bad buttons

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am developing apps with python 3. Python complained that I have an unstable version of tcl/tk. So I installed ActiveTcl (8.5.18) to fix this. But when I used this library the buttons looked very bad:

[image]

So I tried to configure them:

```
mybutton.config(height=2, width=5)
```

But when I specify height they lose their aqua theme:

[image]

If there is not a way to fix this could you please tell me how to downgrade tcl/tk back to the version 8.5.9?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I think that this problem is not related to the particular versions of Tcl/Tk you are mentioning, but it is due to the fact that you are developing for a Mac OS X. It's a quite well-known "issue" the fact you cannot customise everything at will on an OS X... you could try to use `ttk` buttons instead, and try to apply some custom style, but I am afraid you will have a headache...

Comment: @nbro The buttons looked fine in the last version.

Comment: Thank you @nbro! I've used ttk and deployed the aqua theme manually and the buttons looked much better!

Comment: I'm happy my suggestions helped you :)